# Caching in SQL Server 2012 and doing queries - What can I assume and how to use this cache?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, browser-cache

I have a following question:
I am doing two queries - one by one.  These two question has the same "subselect":

First:

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM 
 SomeFunction(id)
WHERE
 A and B and C
CROSS JOIN
 X
```

Second:

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM 
 SomeFunction(id)
WHERE
 A and B and C
CROSS JOIN
 Y
```

As you can see the only difference is between `Y` and `X` parts.  First part of query is the exactly the same.
Can I count on SQLServer that it cache it and second query will be faster than first ? The question is:
When and how can I count on caching in SQLServer ?  I can do it manually, I mean firstly fetch

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM 
 SomeFunction(id)
```

and then use it in first and second query

The context is mybatis and spring-boot, but it doesn't matter here, I think.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong questions here. Are the queries running *fast enough* for you? If so, does it matter whether it was some specific cache or some other means that mean that it is? And if it isn't, shouldn't you be looking at *any* mechanism to speed it up, rather than again focussing on caching, specifically? (It would also help if your queries were even *valid*, preferably with some sample data so that we could even *run* them)

Comment: Why not enable the execution plan and check the result of the execution time?

Answer (score 0):

A page(8KB) is a fundamental unit of storage in SQLServer.Pages belonging to particular table are stored under a logical id..

So when you issue say below query

```
select * from table where id=2
```

let's assume,the id =2 is stored in two pages.SQL will first check,if they are in cache,if they are not,they will be brought to cache and read..

Those two pages will be in cache as long as there is no memory pressure.If there is memory pressure,SQLServer will start evicting cached pages from memory based on LRU algorithm,which roughly translates to less used pages

so there is a chance ,that your next query may read the data from disk or from memory..

Comment: So there is only chance, no guarantee. So I shouldn't count on  caching in SQLerver

Comment: you also can ignore this and check further performance aspects,if your queries are running slow